# How to lookup two different ranges based on row's value Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to do a conditional vlookup but with pandas. Here's the data i'm using

**n_age_scores**

```
type n     aging_n     mini_n   percent_n
new        <30 days       0       0.5543
new        31-50 days     31      0.6446
new        51-100 days    51      0.3134
```

**e_age_scores**

```
type e           aging_e      mini_e   percent_e
expansion        <30 days       0       0.33543
expansion        31-50 days     31      0.4446
expansion        51-100 days    51      0.6134
```

**Dataframe**

```
type        age    score
new          33
new          12
expansion    3
new          4
expansion    100
```

What I want to do is populate score with the percent column of either dataframe based on if the row `type` is new or expansion, an approximate match of value percent.

How do I do this with Pandas?

```
n_age_scores = aging_score_mapping.iloc[:,0:4] 
e_age_scores = aging_score_mapping.iloc[:,-4:9]


    if df['deal_type'] == 'Expansion':
       df = merge.e_age_scores(df, on='age_score')
       if df['deal_type'] == 'new':
          df = merge.n_age_scores(df, on='age_score')
```

I'm not sure how to do this but I think i need to loop and merge with a approximate match and populate age_score with percent_n depending on the type.

Is this possible with pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your custom function to extract the data from the two dataframes and use it with [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

If I understood correctly what you want, the code below shoud do the job.
I called `age_map` the resulting dataframe (those with the `score` column to be populated and `collector` the function which extract the data from `n_age_scores` and `e_age_scores`.

```
def collector(row):
    if row['type'] == 'new':
        return n_age_scores.loc[n_age_scores['mini_n'] < row['age']].iloc[-1]['percent_n']
    elif row['type'] == 'expansion':
        return e_age_scores.loc[e_age_scores['mini_e'] < row['age']].iloc[-1]['percent_e']

age_map['score'] = age_map.apply(collector, axis=1)
```

Using the sample dataframes you provide, `age_map` is:

```
        type  age    score
0        new   33  0.64460
1        new   12  0.55430
2  expansion    3  0.33543
3        new    4  0.55430
4  expansion  100  0.61340
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. This has worked a treat! Thanks again!

Comment: thanks for your answer it did exactly the job I wanted to do. I am however trying to replicate this exact function on two small datasets and do a conditional lookup like the function you wrote but I'm getting an error `IndexError: ('single positional indexer is out-of-bounds', 'occurred at index 0')`

It's really strange but the data is of the same size index wise

Comment: My guess is that you have a case where the first `loc` is empty, so when you do `.iloc[-1]` it raises that error. Cannot say anything more specific without looking at the real data.

Comment: I've made another stackoverflow question here with the data if that helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57199390/conditional-merge-single-indexer-out-of-bounds-occured-at-zero-error-with-pan