# Conditional merge: single indexer out of bounds 'occured at zero' error with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to do a conditional merge using data from two different dataframes
to my original dataframe.

The data for the two dataframes used for the conditional lookup are selected using iloc. One Data frame for new and one for expansion.

```
n_push_count= push_count_mapping.iloc[:,0:4] 
e_push_count = push_count_mapping.iloc[:,-4:9]

        type_n  aging_n mini_n  percent_n
0       New     0       0       0.520833
1       New     1       1       0.318471
2       New     2       2       0.234848
3       New     3       3       0.156627
4       New     4       4       0.129032
5       New     >5      5       0.129630
6       New     5       4       4.500000
7       New     6       5       4.500000
8       New     4       5       4.400000

    type_e      aging_e mini_e  percent_e
0   Expansion   0       0       0.642722
1   Expansion   1       1       0.413793
2   Expansion   2       2       0.260204
3   Expansion   3       3       0.196721
4   Expansion   4       4       0.215385
5   Expansion   >5      5       0.156627
6   Expansion   4       4       66.000000
7   Expansion   >5      5       3.000000
8   Expansion   >5      5       4.000000
```

I want to merge the percent_e or percent_n depending if deal_type is new or expansion to push count score. The length of this dataframe is 40 records. 0-39
This is df2

```
    deal_type    push_count    push_count_score
0   Expansion      0            NaN
1   Expansion      3            NaN
2   New            2            NaN
3   Expansion      0            NaN
```

The function I have below works has worked for a similar set of columns with the same length of data. Here's the full code

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
import pandas as pd
import csv
import json
import numpy as np

n_push_count= push_count_mapping.iloc[:,0:4] 
e_push_count = push_count_mapping.iloc[:,-4:9]

    def add_push_count(row):
        if row['deal_type'] == 'New':
            return n_push_count.loc[n_push_count['mini_n'] < row['push_count']].iloc[-1]['percent_n']
        elif row['deal_type'] == 'Expansion':
            return e_push_count.loc[e_push_count['mini_e'] < row['push_count']].iloc[-1]['percent_e']

    df2['push_count_score'] = df2.apply(add_push_count, axis=1)


    display(df)
```

I'm receiving an error when I run my function

```
 IndexError: ('single positional indexer is out-of-bounds', 'occurred at index 0')
```

Can anyone help or explain what this error is? This function worked for a very similar application in my code but won't even work with a slice of the data I'm working on. df2 being a slice of the dataframe.

Comment: `e_push_count = push_count_mapping.iloc[:,-4:9]`. Why the minus sign in `-4:9`? Should not be `4:9`? Not sure if this will solve the problem, but try with this fix first.

Comment: @Valentino I've tried to remove the minus and I've the same error. Posted a stacktrace here https://gist.github.com/Cally99/57262d45c7dc467ecbbc15ab0301caa2
but the line that's showing the error in the backend code is

```2137         len_axis = len(self.obj._get_axis(axis))
   2138         if key >= len_axis or key < -len_axis:
-> 2139             raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because in some cases `n_push_count.loc[n_push_count['mini_n'] < row['push_count']]` (or the other one with `e_`) returns an empty dataframe. Indexing an empty dataframe with `.iloc[-1]` raises that `IndexError`.

This happens for example because the first row of your `df2` has `push_count` equal to `0`, and the values of `mini_n` column in `e_push_count` dataframe are all zeroes or positive integers.

You need to choose what to do in these cases, and that is a thing only you can decide.

A possibility could be to change the condition from `lesser` to `lesser or equal`: use `<=` instead of `<`.

In this case using your data sample you'll get:

```
   deal_type  push_count  push_count_score
0  Expansion           0          0.642722
1  Expansion           3          0.196721
2        New           2          0.234848
3  Expansion           0          0.642722
```

But if you require that `n_push_count['mini_n']` should be strictly smaller than `row['push_count']`, then you have no field for that value and you must modify the code to keep a null value. To do this, you could wrap the code of the function in a `try except` block:

```
def add_push_count(row):
    try:
        if row['deal_type'] == 'New':
            return n_push_count.loc[n_push_count['mini_n'] < row['push_count']].iloc[-1]['percent_n']
        elif row['deal_type'] == 'Expansion':
            return e_push_count.loc[e_push_count['mini_e'] < row['push_count']].iloc[-1]['percent_e']
    except IndexError:
        return np.NaN
```

Your `df2` will be:

```
   deal_type  push_count  push_count_score
0  Expansion           0               NaN
1  Expansion           3          0.260204
2        New           2          0.318471
3  Expansion           0               NaN
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I've been stuck for days on this problem. I didn't think that the score = 0 would cause a problem. Thanks again!